# Tapestry5.1+seleniumRc Ajax waitForAjax Request

Tags: ajax, selenium, testing, tapestry

Does anyone know how to do `waitForAjaxRequest` using `seleniumRc` (like `waitForPageToLoad`) on tapestry zone? I know there are alternatives like wait for certain element to appear and etc.

I am seeking for a proper `waitForAjaxRequest`, and wish it work on different browsers as well.

I had tried `browserbot`, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `waitForCondition`:

```
selenium.waitForCondition("script", "timeout")
```

while `timeout` is in milliseconds (e.g. 30000) and the `script` is JavaScript that has to return `true` when the condition is fulfilled, e.g.

```
"var value = selenium.getText('foo'); value.match(/bar/);"
```

(See [OpenQA Wiki](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/waitForCondition) for more information. Even though this links to a plugin that was in use with an older version of Selenium, `waitForCondition` is now part of SeleniumRC.)